# MSSQL Copy data from same table modifying part of the text in row

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am trying to copy the rows in the same table and modify them at the same time. Replacing the occurrence of the text with different text. This below, is underlined in the window below "tblGroups.GroupCode" and "PKRowID", as invaild column names.

```
USE [Database];
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblGroups]
       SELECT GroupCode = REPLACE([tblGroups.GroupCode], 'ABC', 'XYZ')
       WHERE PKRowID BETWEEN 777 AND 999;
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert new rows, then you need a `FROM` clause:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblGroups](GroupCode, . . . ) 
    SELECT GroupCode = REPLACE([tblGroups.GroupCode], 'ABC', 'XYZ'),
           . . . 
    FROM [dbo].[tblGroups] g
    WHERE PKRowID BETWEEN 777 AND 999;
```

Note that you probably need to include other columns -- but I don't know what the table really looks like.

If you just want to change the existing rows in place, then use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tblGroups]
    SET GroupCode = REPLACE([tblGroups.GroupCode], 'ABC', 'XYZ')
    WHERE PKRowID BETWEEN 777 AND 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [Database];
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblGroups](GroupCode)
       SELECT REPLACE(GroupCode, 'ABC', 'XYZ')
       FROM tblGroups
       WHERE PKRowID BETWEEN 777 AND 999;
```